# Cannot print dot character in a bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I have a script that bumps a version of a package.json. I can bump the version with this script, but I'm having problems printing a variable, where I'm expecting "1.2.3", but get "1 2 3".

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

# Split string by '.'
IFS='.'
read -r -a array <<< "1.1.3"
array[1]=$((array[1]+1))

VERSION="${array[0]}.${array[1]}.${array[2]}"
echo $VERSION
# 1 2 3

VERSION=`printf "%i.%i.%i" "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"`
echo $VERSION
# 1 2 3

echo $(jq -r '.version = "'"$VERSION"'" ' package.json)
# packaje.json -> "version": "1 2 3"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you've set `IFS` for the whole script, rather than just the one command which needs it. Try `IFS='.' read […]` instead.

Also, if you [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) you won't have this issue, because the output won't be split by `$IFS`.

Comment: Work perfectly. I changed to `IFS='.' read -r -a array <<< "1.1.3"` and solved it. As @harshit kumar answered you could `unset IFS` or `IFS=''`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing quotes.  The shell is splitting VERSION on . before it passes the arguments to echo.

```
$ VERSION=1.2.3
$ echo $VERSION
1.2.3
$ IFS=.
$ echo $VERSION
1 2 3
$ echo "$VERSION"
1.2.3
```